# How to set xpath for non sequencing words in one attribute?

Tags: html, dom, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have one tag :

```
<span class="abc pqr and xyz">
```

Now I want to identify this tag in DOM with the help of `xpath`.

I have tried this:

```
//span[contains(@class,'abc pqr')].....
```

Here `and` term is frequently change.Just `abc,pqr,xyz` are constant.

How can I identify this element with use of all three set value.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine several `contains` queries with an 'and' operator:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'abc') and contains(@class, 'pqr') and contains(@class, 'xyz')]
```

If the classes are always in certain positions or always together, you could go for:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'abc pqr') and contains(@class, 'xyz')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
//span[starts-with(@class,'abc pqr')][ends-with(@class, 'xyz')]
```

or:

```
//span[starts-with(@class,'abc pqr') and ends-with(@class, 'xyz')]
```